# ConstraintLayout margins not working

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

Using the xml below the `marginTop` is getting ignored if the view's visibility that I'm constrained to is gone.

This happens with the latest layout lib version at this time `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4`

Example:

`tvMessage` and `ivCommentImage` are `visible` - the 16dp top margin on `llLeftActions` and `llRightActions` is working fine. If the `ivCommentImage` is `gone` the margin is ignored.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<!-- some more views here -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        style="@style/SocialFeed.Description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfile"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
        tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_140chars"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCommentImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMessage"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLeftActions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tvMessage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCommentImage"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRightActions"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/gCenter"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tvMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCommentImage"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's working completely as intended -- note that you added `layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"` on `@id/llLeftActions` and `@id/llRightActions`...

Which means that when the widget they are pointing to (`@id/ivCommentImage`) is marked as gone, the margin that will be used for the top connection will be... 0dp, and not the margin of 16dp. That's what those attributes are here for! :)

check the documentation on [visibility behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#VisibilityBehavior) and [gone margin attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#GoneMargin)

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Available chats"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listChats"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>
```

Please notice the last line, adding constraints around the edges makes the constraint work.

You can also use the design view in Studio, and drag and drop the constraints between objects.

Comment: i have the same problem, 
using `@+id/textView` works, but `@id/textView` not working.
why should `@+id/textView` not just `@id/textView`